# Error when I try to create an .accdb file in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, adox

This is my code that creates an .accdb file if it can't find one :

```
Catalog cat = new CatalogClass();
string createStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/saveDB.accdb;";
cat.Create(createStr);
Table tbl = new Table();
tbl.Name = "saveDB";
tbl.Columns.Append("ID", DataTypeEnum.adGUID);
tbl.Columns.Append("Tensiune", DataTypeEnum.adDouble);
tbl.Columns.Append("Frecventa", DataTypeEnum.adDouble);
tbl.Columns.Append("Rezistenta", DataTypeEnum.adDouble);
tbl.Columns.Append("Inductanta", DataTypeEnum.adDouble);
tbl.Columns.Append("Capacitate", DataTypeEnum.adDouble);
tbl.Columns.Append("Elemente", DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 25);
tbl.Columns.Append("Tip", DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 25);
cat.Tables.Append(tbl);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(tbl);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cat.Tables);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cat.ActiveConnection);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cat);
```

But when I run it in the program i get this runtime error :

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Not a valid file name.
   at ADOX.CatalogClass.Create(String ConnectString)
```

I can't figure what's the problem with the file name, so if anyone has any idea, please help.

Comment: The path is not of the format I would use. Try it with an actual FullPath srting i.e. C:\SomeDir\AnotherDir\File.accdb...

Comment: I tought about that but i can't really do that because i will give this program to other people and i can't know where they will install it.

Comment: I fixed it. I'll post the solution i found when the site allows me (7 hours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i finally found a workaround based on Killercam's idea he posted in the comments and i'll post it here in case someone needs it sometime.
Build the connection string like this :

```
Catalog cat = new CatalogClass();
string cntPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string createStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + cntPath + "\\saveDB.accdb;";
cat.Create(createStr);
```